# Python renders wrong page using web.py

Tags: python, pycharm, web.py

I am trying to teach myself Python.  I have the following code in my controller.py file:

```
import web

urls = {
    '/', 'home',
    '/register', 'registerclick'
}

render = web.template.render("views/templates", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

# Classes/Routes

class home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.home()

class registerclick:
    def GET(self):
        return render.register()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And this is the code in my MainLayout.html:

```
$def with (page)

$var css: static/css/bootstrap.css
$var js1: static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js static/js/bootstrap.js         static/js/material.min.js static/js/ripple.min.js static/js/scripty.js

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeWizard</title>

    $if self.css:
        $for style in self.css.split():
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="$style" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="navbar navbar-info navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">CodeWizard</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="waves-effect" href="/">Home Feed<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/discover">Discover<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/profile">Profile<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/settings">Settings<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="/register" class="btn btn-raised btn-default waves-effect">Register</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        $:page
    </div>

    $if self.js1:
        $for script in self.js1.split():
            <script src="$script"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have 2 additional files (home.html, and register.html) and I have bootstrap available (although that has nothing to do with my issue).

When I start the application and I open a browser and enter localhost:8080 as the url, MainLayout.html is loaded into the browser (which I expect) but the contents of register.html are loaded into $:page and I don't know why.

When I remove the second entry from the urls and remove the regnsterclick class from controller.py, the MainLayout.html page is loaded and nothing appears to be loaded into $:page.

Any ideas why the contents of register.html get presented?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you open your browser with localhost:8080, you should be seeing an error as you don't have anything defined for that URL. Perhaps you have an 'old' version of your webserver still running on 8080? That symptoms you describe do not match your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining `urls` with braces, you made it a `set`, which is unordered. You need to define `urls` as a `tuple` which can be done using parentheses.

This answer explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46633252/2150542

Comment: I changed the braces to parentheses and it worked perfectly!  Thank you very much.